# How can I export data from my Azure Pipeline to display a trend chart in Azure DevOps Dashboard? (e.g. trend chart for migrate unit testing framework)

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I would like to migrate my unit tests library from enzyme to react-testing-library. And I want to show a trend report in my dashboard.

Pretty much like this from the Sentry blog *1:
[image]

And I can already calculate the # of files per each framework with scripts in my Azure Pipeline. More specifically, I can do this:

```bash
COUNT=`grep -rlE --include=\*.test.tsx --include=\*.test.jsx 'enzyme' ./src | wc -l`
echo $COUNT
echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=enzyme;]$COUNT"
```

and calculate the ratio and so on.

What I want to ask is, is there a way to export these numbers from my pipeline so that Azure DevOps can consume them to render a trend chart in the dashboard or any place? How?

**Reference**

1. https://blog.sentry.io/sentrys-frontend-tests-migrating-from-enzyme-to-react-testing-library/